# How to use a word or sentence in one line to place in another line without deleting the previous line?

Tags: notepad++

is there a method to copy the answer from one line and replace it another, without affecting the original line? for ex

Texture="cnwl"

icao_airline=

i would like it to know that icao_airline= the first three letter in quotation

Answer (score 1):

Not totaly sure I well understand your needs, but I guess you wqnt:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `Texture="(...).*?"[\s\S]+?icao_airline=\K.*$`
- Replace with: `"$1"`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
Texture="           # literally
(...)               # group 1, 3 any characters but newline
.*?                 # 0 or more any character but newline, not greedy
"                   # quote
[\s\S]+?            # 1 or more any character
icao_airline=       # literally
\K                  # forget all wee have seen until this position
.*                  # 0 or more any character but newline
$                   # end of line
```

**Replacement:**

```
"$1"          # content of group 1 surounded with quotes
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: thank you so much sorry for the late reply, you are a genius

Comment: @AvisPorter: You're welcome, glad it helps. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)